# How to show multiple news feed on same wall?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very simple question but dont know how to do it with best way.

As you know on FB we see our friends posts and the sharings from the fan pages or company pages. Like they share jobs or any update about their products.

Now you also know that those company profiles or fan pages are not like the other friends or users they are created by other users. So, I have three tables suppose,

- users
- companies [different login signup than users]
- posts

Now I want that when a user A logged in, He can see all posts by his friends plus posts by the companies he is following.

So, If user A has three friends B,C,D and he is also following a company profile 'FFTECH' then user A should see all posts by his friends and the company.

Now, here is my problem comes, I fetches posts from post table and join them from users table and print on wall. But now how to fetch and print the posts by companies? 
They have different fields names in company table so how to do that?

User A shared something.....

FFTECH share something....

in users table we have fields like fname etc but in company we have cname etc. So how to use single wall file to show all feeds on same place. And also we need to take care of dat as well, I mean we cant show all friends feed first and then all company posts in the end. They should be on their proper place according to time of sharing as we see in FB

I just need a idea not the code may be. Appreciated.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a unique identifier for each type of posts - let's say you add a new column to both tables, say, type. For the user tables, the type can be set to '1', and then for that of companies you can set it to '2'.

By doing this you can avoid conflating both types of data and retain the ability to tell which posts are made by users and which ones are made by companies.

Assuming that you have gotten all the data into an array and are looping through each item to display the posts, you can try:

```
while(...) {
    if($data['type'] == 1) {
        // Parse user posts
    } elseif($data['type'] == 2) {
        // Parse company posts
    }
}
```